# Data Grid View loses it's binding with the form after I apply search on it

Tags: c#

I'm new with Visual Studio and C#. 
I've created a registration form and a data grid view. They are all connected with the Database with the Data Source. So when I click a record in the grid view, the data appear in the form. Problem is, when i apply search/filtering on the grid view, somehow, it loses it's binding. So when i select a record from the grid view it doesn't show the data on the form.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bYh5.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc3Ts.png)

I could really use some help! Thank you.

This is how it's connected. Visual Studio did it by it's self. I also tried to do it with a connection.

```
 DataTable dbdataset;
 private void ToddlerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.patientsTableAdapter.Fill(this.gridPatientsDataSet1.Patients);
        childrenAndToddlers();


 this.childToddlerTableAdapter.Fill(this.tMA_DatabaseDataSet.childToddler);
        this.childToddler_generalTableAdapter.Fill(this.tMA_DatabaseDataSet.childToddler_general);





        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(global::TMA.Properties.Settings.Default.TMA_DatabaseConnectionString);

        try
        {

            string query2 = "SELECT * FROM childToddler_general";
            SqlCommand exeSql = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = exeSql;
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            metroGrid2.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

and this is the filtering code

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (metroComboBox2.Text == ("ID"))
            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(dbdataset);
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("convert(id_ct, 'System.String') Like '%{0}%' ", textBox3.Text);
                metroGrid2.DataSource = dv;
            }

            if (metroComboBox2.Text == ("Name"))
            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(dbdataset);
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("aname like '%{0}%'", textBox3.Text);
                metroGrid2.DataSource = dv;
            }

            if (metroComboBox2.Text == ("Surname"))
            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(dbdataset);
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("asurname like '%{0}%'", textBox3.Text);
                metroGrid2.DataSource = dv;
            }

            }
```

Comment: `I'm new with Visual Studio and C#` So why the VB tag?  You are also new to SO, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Show the code please. Show code how you bind data to the DataGridView, HOw selected row bounded to the form, and how you apply filter